# Frobenius map and Hopf algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras

I was wondering if I can get some help understanding a problem.

Namely, consider the Frobenius map of $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebra $f:A \rightarrow  A$ given by $a \mapsto a^p$. I showed that if $A$ is an $\mathbb{F}_p$-Hopf algebra then the map $f$ is a homomorphism of Hopf algebras i.e. it is compatible with comultiplication. Now I need to "compute the kernel (as Hopf algebras)", as stated in the problem. What does this mean exactly? Why is this different than just computing the kernel of $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebras?

Further, I need to compute the Frobenius map and it's kernel in the case when $A$ is the Hopf algebra representing the additive group functor $\mathbb{G}_a$. Any hint as to how to go about doing this? I tried again with the requirement that it should be compatible with comultiplication defined on $A$, but I don't know what I am supposed to conclude about the definition of the map $f$ and it's kernel from that.

Comment: Do you know what the Hopf algebra representing the additive group functor is?

Comment: A morphism of (commutative) Hopf algebras corresponds to a morphism of algebraic groups. On the group side, the kernel of the group homomorphism is itself a group, so it has attached to it a Hopf algebra. That is probably what the firt part is about.

Comment: I do. It's $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ with comultiplication defined by $x \mapsto x \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes x$. Right?

Comment: Well, then you should be able to describe explicitly the Frobenius map.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Then I just get $p(x) \mapsto p(x^p \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes x^p)$, is that what you mean? And again for the kernel you mean that I should find the Hopf algebra representing the kernel of the natural transformation of group functors?

Comment: Well, the Frobenius map of *any* Hopf algebra $A$ is, as you yourself wrote, the map $a\in A\mapsto a^p\in A$; you can specialize this to the one corresponding to the additive group. Regarding the other part: yes.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Could you help with what is the transformation of group functors that is induced by the Frobenius map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $k$ be the field with $p$ elements, $A$ be the Hopf algebra $k[t]$ with $\Delta(t)=t\otimes1+1\otimes t$, and let $F:A\to A$ be its Frobenius map.

If $B$ is a $k$-algebra, then there is a bijection $\Phi:\hom(A,B)\to B$ (with $\hom$ denoting algebra homomorphisms) given by $\Phi(f)=f(t)$. The comultiplication on $A$ turns $\hom(A,B)$ into a group, and under the bijection $\Phi$ this group corresponds precisely to the additive group $B$.

Now the map $F:A\to A$ gives us a map $f\in\hom(A,B)\mapsto f\circ F\in\hom(A,B)$. Using $\Phi$ to transport this to $B$, you can easily check that that map corresponds to the map $b\in B\mapsto b^p\in B$, which is, as expected, a homomorphism of additive groups. The map induced by $F$ is therefore $b\in B\mapsto b^p\in B$. Its kernel is the subgroup of elements of $B$ whose $p$th power is zero.

It is easy to see that the functor mapping an algebra $B$ to the set of its elements whose $p$th power is zero is represented by the algebra $k[t]/(t^p)$. This algebra has to be a Hopf algebra, as it represents a group values functor. You should find it.

Comment: Understood. Thank you. Just to check, in the general case, for any k-Hopf algebra $A$ (not necessarily representing $\mathbb{G}_a$, since there is no bijection such as $\Phi$ the most I can say about the kernel of the natural transformation induced by $F$ (call it $\varphi$) is that for any k-algebra $B$ we have 
 Ker $\varphi(B)$ = $\{ f \in h^A(B) | f \circ F(a)=e(B)$ for all $a \in A\} = \{f \in h^A(B) | f(a^p)=e(B)$ for all $a \in A\}$. There is nothing more to it correct?

Comment: Try a concrete example, like $SL_2$.